# Using apache_request_headers()

Tags: php

I'm trying to use `apache_request_headers()` to get some request headers. I'm trying to get this output into one $ApacheHeaders:

```
<?php
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
?>
```

When I try calling it again like:

```
OTHER_PLACE => "{\"Extra headers $header: $value <br />\"}",
```

I'm not getting the same result as using `echo`. How can I join all this into one `$ApacheHeaders` to get the same result as echo?

Example:

```
   OTHER_PLACE => "{\"Extra headers $ApacheHeaders\"}",
```

Comment: Try breaking the problem down. Ignore the fact that you're dealing with Apache headers, and start with a simple array like `['foo'=>'hello', 'bar'=>'world']`. You want to build a string, based on that array.

Comment: Thanks @IMSoP. this is because there are multiple lines? I'm not sure on how to build a string  call $ApacheHeaders from apache_request_headers(). I will keep trying

Comment: I'm looking to get the same result that `echo "$header: $value <br />\n";` gives

Comment: That `echo` statement is only displaying *one header*, you just happen to be calling it multiple times; you want a string containing *all the headers*. Again, don't try to build a string called `$ApacheHeaders` from `apache_request_headers()`. Try to build a string called `$test_string` from `$test_array = ['foo'=>'hello', 'bar'=>'world']`. Look up "concatenation", and think about how you can combine *multiple strings* into *one string*. There are lots of ways to do it, and all will work just as well with the array returned by `apache_request_headers` once you get them working.

Comment: I understand that you saying but I’m a bit confused I like use this as I use something like `$remoteRef = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`. I understand I need to build  `$test_string` from `$test_array` using something similar to `foreach` correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
$ApacheHeaders = '';
foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    $ApacheHeaders .= "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
echo $ApacheHeaders;
```

Comment: Thanks @Trupti when trying to add `$ApacheHeaders`  to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS >> content at sendgrid-php https://sendgrid.com/blog/create-basic-contact-form-sendgrid-php/) I'm getting this error `{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Request","field":null,"help":null}]}`